# import dynamic xml to sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

This sample XML shown here is what I want to import into a SQL Server table. The XML tags are dynamic here.( xml element name differ in othe xml files. Also number of xml elements in root and child nodes are different for each xml file)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:heal="http://healthedge.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <heal:getClaimDetailsByHccID>
         <claimHccNumber>10</claimHccNumber>
         <claimDetailFlags>
            <includeAccounts>a</includeAccounts>
            <includeAccumulators>b</includeAccumulators>           
         </claimDetailFlags>       
         <claimFilterParameters>
            <includeTransientStates>true</includeTransientStates>
            <mostRecentPaymentOnly>false</mostRecentPaymentOnly>
         </claimFilterParameters>
      </heal:getClaimDetailsByHccID>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to store xml into 3 different  tables, one table for each level element(root,child, sub child)  the tag names are stored as row data.

Output should look like this:

Parent table

```
id   value      
---------------------------
1    getClaimDetailsByHccID
```

Root table

```
parent_id   root id    name                     value
------------------------------------------------------
   1          1        claimHccNumber           10
   1          2        claimDetailFlags         null
   1          3        claimFilterParameters    null
```

Child table

```
root id   child id  name                        value
--------------------------------------------------------
   2        1       includeAccounts             a
   2        2       includeAccumulators         b
   3        3       includeTransientStates      TRUE
   3        4       mostRecentPaymentOnly       FALSE
```

i tried using below code, here value is not populating correctly for rootTable code:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ChildTbl;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS RootTbl;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ParentTbl;

CREATE TABLE ParentTbl (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [value] VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE RootTbl (root_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, parent_id INT, [name] VARCHAR(100), [value] VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE ChildTbl (child_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, parent_id INT, [name] VARCHAR(100), [value] VARCHAR(100));

DECLARE @xml XML = N'
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:heal="http://healthedge.com">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <heal:getClaimDetailsByHccID>
            <claimHccNumber>10</claimHccNumber>
            <claimDetailFlags>
                <includeAccounts>a</includeAccounts>
                <includeAccumulators>b</includeAccumulators>
            </claimDetailFlags>
            <claimFilterParameters>
                <includeTransientStates>true</includeTransientStates>
                <mostRecentPaymentOnly>false</mostRecentPaymentOnly>
            </claimFilterParameters>
        </heal:getClaimDetailsByHccID>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @ParentID INT
    , @RootID INT;

-- Parent table handling
-- =========================================================================
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soapenv
    , 'http://healthedge.com' AS heal), rs AS
(
    SELECT c.value('local-name(heal:*[1])','VARCHAR(100)') AS [value]
    FROM @xml.nodes('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body') AS t(c)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.ParentTbl (value)
SELECT * FROM rs;

SET @ParentID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

-- RootTbl table handling
-- =========================================================================
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soapenv
    , 'http://healthedge.com' AS heal), rs AS
(
    SELECT c.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(100)') AS [name]
        , c.value('(*[1]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS [value]
    --  ,c.value('./.','VARCHAR(100)') AS [value1]
    FROM @xml.nodes('/*/*/*/*') AS t(c)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.RootTbl (parent_id, [name], [value])
SELECT @ParentID, * FROM rs;

SET @RootID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
----child----
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soapenv
    , 'http://healthedge.com' AS heal), rs AS
(
    SELECT c.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(100)') AS [name]
        , c.value('./.','VARCHAR(100)') AS [value]
    FROM @xml.nodes('/*/*/*/*/*') AS t(c)
    
)
INSERT INTO dbo.ChildTbl (parent_id, [name], [value])
SELECT @RootID, * FROM rs;

-- test
SELECT * FROM dbo.ParentTbl;
SELECT * FROM dbo.RootTbl
SELECT * FROM dbo.ChildTbl;
```

Comment: and what have you done so far? what part are you stuck on?

Comment: @hanshernrik, I stuck on assigning root id to child table, and value field in root table not populating correctly. i have copied my code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is not so clear what it means *"...The XML tags are dynamic here..."*.

Please try the following solution.

```
USE tempdb;
GO

-- DDL and sample data population, start
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.ChildTbl;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.RootTbl;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.ParentTbl;

CREATE TABLE dbo.ParentTbl (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [value] VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE dbo.RootTbl (root_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    , parent_id INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.ParentTbl(ID), [name] VARCHAR(100), [value] VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE dbo.ChildTbl (child_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    , parent_id INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.RootTbl(root_id), [name] VARCHAR(100), [value] VARCHAR(100));

/*
DECLARE @xml XML = N'
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:heal="http://healthedge.com">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <heal:getClaimDetailsByHccID>
            <claimHccNumber>10</claimHccNumber>
            <claimDetailFlags>
                <includeAccounts>a</includeAccounts>
                <includeAccumulators>b</includeAccumulators>
            </claimDetailFlags>
            <claimFilterParameters>
                <includeTransientStates>true</includeTransientStates>
                <mostRecentPaymentOnly>false</mostRecentPaymentOnly>
            </claimFilterParameters>
        </heal:getClaimDetailsByHccID>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';
*/
DECLARE @xml XML = N'<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:heal="http://healthedge.com">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <heal:getClaimDetailsByHccID>
            <claimHccNumber>10</claimHccNumber>
            <claimDetailFlags>
                <includeAccounts>1</includeAccounts>
                <includeAccumulators>2</includeAccumulators>
                <includeBenefitNetwork>3</includeBenefitNetwork>
                <includeBenefitPlan>4</includeBenefitPlan>
                <includeExternalRepricerResult>101</includeExternalRepricerResult>
                <includeFundedAccounts>5</includeFundedAccounts>
                <includeIngenixExternalLineResult>102</includeIngenixExternalLineResult>
                <includePractitioner>6</includePractitioner>
                <includeProcedureInformation>7</includeProcedureInformation>
                <includeProduct>8</includeProduct>
                <includeReportingCategories>9</includeReportingCategories>
                <includeReportingCategoriesDescription>10</includeReportingCategoriesDescription>
                <includeRepricerName>11</includeRepricerName>
                <includeSupplier>12</includeSupplier>
                <includeSupplierInvoice>13</includeSupplierInvoice>
                <includeSupplierLocation>14</includeSupplierLocation>
                <includeWithholding>15</includeWithholding>
            </claimDetailFlags>
            <claimFilterParameters>
                <asOfDateTime>51</asOfDateTime>
                <claimState>52</claimState>
                <includeAllPreviouslyPaid>53</includeAllPreviouslyPaid>
                <includeReversedClaimHeader>54</includeReversedClaimHeader>
                <includeTransientStates>55</includeTransientStates>
                <mostRecentPaymentOnly>56</mostRecentPaymentOnly>
                <paymentBatchNumber>57</paymentBatchNumber>
                <paymentDateRangeEnd>58</paymentDateRangeEnd>
                <paymentDateRangeStart>59</paymentDateRangeStart>
                <usePlanTypeFromClaimLine>60</usePlanTypeFromClaimLine>
            </claimFilterParameters>
        </heal:getClaimDetailsByHccID>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @ParentID INT
    , @RootID INT;

-- Parent table handling
-- =========================================================================
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soapenv
    , 'http://healthedge.com' AS heal), rs AS
(
    SELECT c.value('local-name(heal:*[1])','VARCHAR(100)') AS [value]
    FROM @xml.nodes('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body') AS t(c)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.ParentTbl (value)
SELECT * FROM rs;

SET @ParentID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

-- RootTbl table handling
-- =========================================================================
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soapenv
    , 'http://healthedge.com' AS heal), rs AS
(
    SELECT c.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(100)') AS [name]
        , c.value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS [value]
    FROM @xml.nodes('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/heal:getClaimDetailsByHccID/*[1]') AS t(c)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.RootTbl (parent_id, [name], [value])
SELECT @ParentID, * FROM rs;


-- claimDetailFlags handling
-- =========================================================================
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soapenv
    , 'http://healthedge.com' AS heal), rs AS
(
    SELECT c.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(100)') AS [name]
        , NULL AS [value]
    FROM @xml.nodes('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/heal:getClaimDetailsByHccID/claimDetailFlags') AS t(c)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.RootTbl (parent_id, [name], [value])
SELECT @ParentID, * FROM rs;

SET @RootID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();


-- ChildTbl handling
-- =========================================================================
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soapenv
    , 'http://healthedge.com' AS heal), rs AS
(
    SELECT c.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(100)') AS [name]
        , c.value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS [value]
    FROM @xml.nodes('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/heal:getClaimDetailsByHccID/claimDetailFlags/*') AS t(c)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.ChildTbl (parent_id, [name], [value])
SELECT @RootID, * FROM rs;

-- claimFilterParameters handling
-- =========================================================================
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soapenv
    , 'http://healthedge.com' AS heal), rs AS
(
    SELECT c.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(100)') AS [name]
        , NULL AS [value]
    FROM @xml.nodes('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/heal:getClaimDetailsByHccID/claimFilterParameters') AS t(c)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.RootTbl (parent_id, [name], [value])
SELECT @ParentID, * FROM rs;

SET @RootID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

-- ChildTbl handling
-- =========================================================================
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soapenv
    , 'http://healthedge.com' AS heal), rs AS
(
    SELECT c.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(100)') AS [name]
        , c.value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS [value]
    FROM @xml.nodes('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/heal:getClaimDetailsByHccID/claimFilterParameters/*') AS t(c)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.ChildTbl (parent_id, [name], [value])
SELECT @RootID, * FROM rs;

-- test
SELECT * FROM dbo.ParentTbl;
SELECT * FROM dbo.RootTbl
SELECT * FROM dbo.ChildTbl;
```

Comment: Hi, Dynamic in the sense xml tag element name.. other xml file can have different child element name.                                                                                                                              for example, today i got file with root element <claim_detail_flag> other xml file may have name like <claim_condition>.. here xml tag elements are not static.

Comment: Also, number of child element nodes varies in different xml files.

Comment: @Pradeep, my understanding that you are processing SOAP messages. They have predefined standard element names: `soapenv:Envelope`, `soapenv:Body`, etc. So your root is always the same.

Comment: @Pradeep, I updated the answer based on your clarifications.

Comment: Thanks, here basic idea is to store different soap messages in the table. so in other soap messages elements names will be different. above i have copied the sample query.. there I am blocked with 'id' and  'value' field logic.